# How to sort nvarchar time value in SQL Server according to DESC

Tags: sql-server, database

Data example:

```
AtrxId      AtrxDate   AtrxTime  AtrxDes
------------------------------------------
CAS-000001  05-03-2018  12:43 PM  Cash
INV-000001  05-03-2018  11:04 AM  Credit
```

I need the output sorted according to time in a particular day:

```
AtrxId      AtrxDate   AtrxTime   AtrxDes
-----------------------------------------
INV-000001  05-03-2018 11:04 AM   Credit
CAS-000001  05-03-2018 12:43 PM   Cash
```

Comment: According to your output, Ascending sorting needed but your question heading is descending. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

1) Why is it nvarchar? Just asking... this will likely cause many problems for you down the line, unless you need it to be nvarchar because it needs to sometimes accept invalid dates.

This should work. This assumes that both AtrxDate and AtrxTime are nvarchar. It also assumes that there are always valid dates and times in the fields. If either are not valid, then the TRY_CONVERT will return null, which basically means that those will be sorted first:

```
SELECT
    AtrxId
    , AtrxDate
    , AtrxTime
    , AtrxDes
FROM tablenamehere t
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(AtrxDate + ' ' + AtrxTime AS datetime) DESC
```

I'm not sure if you want it listed in forward or backward order by date/time (the example is listed in forward order, but the question's subject line says DESC), but if you want it in forward order, it's just a matter of replacing DESC with ASC. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query. According to your sorting requirement, put "`ASC`" or "`DESC`"

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (AtrxId VARCHAR(100), AtrxDate DATE,  AtrxTime TIME, AtrxDes VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 'CAS-000001', '05-03-2018', '12:43 PM', 'Cash' UNION ALL SELECT 'INV-000001','05-03-2018','11:04 AM','Credit'

SELECT * FROM @TABLE ORDER BY AtrxDate,AtrxTime
```

Or you can try the following `select` query

```
SELECT * FROM @TABLE ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), AtrxDate, 112) 
  + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), AtrxTime, 108))
```